# Visual Studio 2010 automatic code unfolding

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fortran90

I'm having an odd problem with VS 2010. I'm working in Fortran 90, and dealing with some sizable modules, each with a number of subroutines. To stay organized, I want to keep most of the subroutines collapsed (folded, what-have-you) using the code outlining feature. However, when I start typing, the entire file sometimes re-expands automatically, causing me to lose track of where I'm typing (the cursor generally doesn't move in the document, though the entire document moves when it is re-expanded). No options or resources seem to speak to this "undocumented feature". Is there a way to get the code-outlining (folding, what-have-you) to work normally? I'd really like not having to scroll through thousands of lines of code, so leaving it fully-expanded all the time is not a very attractive option.

Edit: I am aware of the keyboard shortcuts for user control. My problem is with the program re-expanding my code on its own, without any user input on the matter.

Comment: There are a couple of Visual Studio integrations for Fortran.  Which one are you using?

Comment: Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2013 is the one I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally have to perform maintenance work on a legacy VB.NET application. To spare my senses from being overwhelmed I use the following keyboard shortcuts so that I am only confronted with a couple of open methods at a time. It sounds like that's what you need.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to collapse everything in
  the file to function definitions.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to toggle expansion of the
  current collapsed area.

Comment: I did manage to find the keyboard shortcuts. My problem is the code re-expanding on it's own entirely, a very unusual and undesirable behavior.

Comment: @bythenumbers: Is that re-expanding behaviour something that only happens with Fortran files? If not then could you describe how to reproduce the behaviour using VB, C# or C++? If I can reproduce it myself then I can better advise how to fix it.

Comment: Can't say if it happens in other languages, sorry. I'm just mentioning it because Fortran isn't built-in, so it could be an interaction between vanilla VS 2010 and the Fortran add-on. All I've found that triggers it is having only some subroutines collapsed and typing in an expanded one causes the others to expand without my say-so.